# Display numbers in between in SQL

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

I have a CTE that creates three fields. 
MemberID, startDate and EndDate.
I want to create a subsequent CTE that will add a new field called MemberInYears.
This new field should have all the years where a member has been active.

```
MemberID    Start   End         MemberInYears
1           2002    2005        2002,2003,2004, 2005
2           2003    2004        2003,2004
3           2001    2003        2001,2002,2003
```

I have tried different approaches, but I can't seem to find an answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: You state you have tried multiple approaches, what were these approaches that did not work?

Answer (score 0):

The following uses SQL Server syntax for string concatenation:

```
with cte as 
      select memberid, start, end, cast(start as varchar(max)) as years, start as y
     from t
     union all
     select memberid, start, end, years + ',' + cast(y+1 as varchar(max)) as years, y+1
     from t
     where y < end
)
select memberid, start, end, years
from cte;
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify your DBMS, but with Postgres you can use `generate_series()`

```
select memberid, 
       min(x) as start, 
       max(x) as "end", 
       string_agg(x::text, ',' order by x) as MemberInYears
from the_cte, 
     generate_series(start, "end") as t(x)
group by memberid
order by memberid;
```